# How to Indent text in LaTeX in a custom way

Tags: latex

Hi I'm new to LaTeX and I'm having some troubles in write a Use Case Specification using the style in this picture.I've tried using listings but i can't succeed in underlying some words.Anyone can help me?
[image: Use case specification]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a command so you can easily without much typing make multiple usecases, this is the complete latex code with 1 example, you can modify the command, it takes 5 parameters and you can access them with the #:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\spec}[5]{
\begin{description}
    \item[\underline{SpecificaUseCase}] #1 \\
    #2
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-8pt]
            \item[] \underline{pre}: #3
            \item[] \underline{post}: #4
        \end{itemize}
    \item[\underline{FinalSecifica}] #5 \\
\end{description}
}

\begin{document}


\spec{usecasename}{method}{pre stuff}{post stuff}{final}

\end{document}
```

The result of this code is somthing like this: [image]

Comment: You are the best!Thank you very much!